How to use localization resource file?
I am developing a blazor server app and now I want to use localization.
I create res1.en.resx and res1.fr.resx, but I can't create a designer class, it throw an exception, but no logs. I tried to create a normal resource file, I succedded.
So I think maybe ResXFileCodeGenerator doesn't support localization resource file? If I can't create the designer class, I can't user IStringLocalizer either, for no class can be passed in as generic arguments.







Please tell us if what version of blazor you are using and if its client or server. Check the access modifier on the resource files, a recent project I did .net 8 had them set to private by default I had to change them to internal. Include any error messages you have got and what you have tried.

Blazor localization is supported and IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizer are supported in Blazor apps. Document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I had a test in my side with VS 2022 and .net 7 blazor server application. I followed this official document. Firstly, it mentioned that

IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizer are supported in Blazor apps.

And it doesn't mention the ResXFileCodeGenerator is necessary for IStringLocalizer in blazor server. But I also test it. I had Resource folder and res1.resx res1.fr.resx res1.cn.resx. When I add property ResXFileCodeGenerator to Custom Tool, VS will generate Designer file automatically. But it won't generate file when I add this property to other resx files.

Then I added builder.Services.AddLocalization(); and put below codes just behind app.UseRouting();
var supportedCultures = new[] { "fr", "en-US", "zh-CN" };
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

Then in my Index.razor component, I have codes below which displayed correctly for me. I change the language by modifying the language configuration in browser.
@using BlazorAppHotRelaod.Resources
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using System.Globalization
@inject IStringLocalizer<res1> Loc

<p>
    <b>CurrentCulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
</p>
<p>
    @Loc["Hello"]
</p>




It doesn't work with me! I completely follow your guide and when I add @Loc["hello"], I can only see "hello" instead of "Hello!"

see my edit, I add some pictures of my project

Have you changed the Browser's default language? By the way, in your screenshot, you have the same key&value in difference resource files. In my screenshot, you can see difference current culture and corresponding language, that's because I changed Browser settings. You can go to setting page of the browser to change the default language. @Sciencekill

My browser's default language is Chinese and I have changed the value in Index.zh-CN.resx. It doesn't work according to my newesr edit with two more screenshots.@Tiny Wang

Could you pls let me know whether you restarted the browser after changing the default language and?

Yes. The default language has been Chinese since I bought this computer, and I even restarted the whole computer but no luck. @Tiny Wang

Could you provide your project for me? I would like to have a look and have a try. Maybe Github or other cloud drive.

In your screenshot, it shows "hello", but in your resource file, the key is Hello and the value are good morning and '早'. I'm afraid you used a wrong key, maybe you can try @localizer["Hello"]? I already deleted my test project. In my post I already shared all my changes for the localizer.

Still no luck. After I changed, it only shows Hello. I'll upload my project in a minute, and you can have a try

Have a look. https://1drv.ms/u/s!At9xMjbIkHMjgfdX5lk93x43vUAbeQ?e=JoeF5y

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

comment your line options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; in program.cs

@Sciencekill Does it worked for you? I test with your project, and that worked in my side.

OK, I'm so sorry to let you wait for such a long time. It works. Thanks a lot!

I'm glad to see it worked for you. Congratulation : )
